# Pentaho: How to rollup time

Tags: time, pentaho, etl

I have time for example I have in records time written in this way: `00:02:24` or `15:22:45`, and now I want to make another column (hours), where can be values for example for time `02:43:22` is value 2, or for time `23:22:14`, is value 23 and so on. But I don't know how can I do that, I tried number range, but unsuccessfully.

Here is a picture, how i want to be:

[image: Time And Hours]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Modified JavaScript Value](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Modified+Java+Script+Value) step.

I do not know which type is your Time.

- If it is a String, a `var Hour = Time.substr(0,2);` will do.
- If it is a Date, use `var Hour = Time.getHour();`.
- If the type is something else, then convert in a String first.

[image]

To do this:

1. drag-and.drop the step `Modified JavaScript Value`and link it to the data flow provider (in the example a `Data grid`).
2. edit this step and add your script. (Note that you can quickly add the input variable with a double click. Note also that clicking on the `Transformation Function` in the left menu gives you the list of available function additional to the Javascript built-in collection).
3. Click on the `Get variable` button, keep the variable you need (here Hour), and define/redefine its type (here String).
4. That's done: OK and preview.
5. If needed, adapt to the type of your input flow. For example `Hour = Hour+''` to force a type conversion into a String.

Comment: Can you explain this code more in detail, or please provide example. Thank you

Comment: Sure, I added an image of the ktr, under the assumption the variable `Time` is a `String`.